# JavaScript Constructor Not Called

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

I have a function to implement inheritance:

```
inherit = function(base) {
    var child = function() { console.log('Crappy constructor.'); };
    child.prototype = new base;
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    return child;
}
```

I thought I could use it like this:

```
var NewClass = inherit(BaseClass);
NewClass.prototype.constructor = function() {
    console.log('Awesome constructor.');
}
```

But when I create a new instance of *NewClass* like this:

```
var instance = new NewClass();
```

I get message *Crappy constructor.* being printed to the console. Why isn't constructor overwritten? And how do I overwrite it?

Comment: Objects inherit from their constructor's prototype, not their own. Add methods to `BaseClass.prototype` to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return `child`, which is a function to print `Crappy constructor`. No matter what, if you call that function, `Crappy constructor` will be printed.

Note the flow:

```
child = function to print 'crappy'
child.prototype.blabla = function to print 'Awesome'
inherit returns child
```

`NewClass = child`

now, when you call NewClass, child gets called.

Other than that, I think you wanted child.constructor.prototype rather than prototype.constructor.

*Edit*: Please see more about inheritance in Javascript [here](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html).

Comment: OK, I think I see your point. For some reason I thought constructor is an actual function which is automatically called when new instance is created and that's why we want to override like I did in *inherit* function.

Comment: Yep, that would be the case in some languages, AFAIC python and php, but javascript is a prototype-based, not class-based language, so things are designed a bit differently. See edit for a link.